# More than once in an arrayList with user input

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

In the code below I need to check if a number appears more than once in an `ArrayList`. The user inputs a number to consult, and if it exist in the `array` and there are more than one the messages, "appears more than once is displayed". I have been trying to do this but I don't know how.

This is the `main` class:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    if (Metodos.moreThanOne(list, number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " appears more than once.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(number + " does not appear more than once.");
    }
```

This is the method:

```
public static boolean moreThanOne(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
    for (Integer in : list) {
        if (list.contains(number) && in==in) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
if (list.lastIndexOf(element) != list.indexOf(element)) {
  return true; // you have at least two numbers
} else {
  return false; // element is not exist or you have only one element
}
```

Comment: Why not directly this? `return list.lastIndexOf(element) != list.indexOf(element);`

Comment: @RolandIllig because if requested element is not exist you will get -1 from the left and from the right

Comment: But your code does exactly the same, just with more lines.

Comment: @RolandIllig excuse me, it is the same

Comment: Oh no, not this `if true return true else false` pattern again.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean moreThanOne(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) 
    {
      int count = 0;
      for (Integer in : list) {
          if (number == in) {
              count++;
          }
      }
      if(count > 1)
         return true;
      else 
         return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class StartHere {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type a number: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
    scanner.close();
    if(moreThanOnce(list, number)){
        System.out.println("The number appears more than once.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The number doesn't appear more than once.");
    }

}

public static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int number) {
    boolean bool = false;
    int counter = 0;
    for (Integer value : list) {
        if (value == number) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter > 1){
        bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
}
}
```

Just a tip: you should improve your english, so it's easier to understand your question. A great way of doing this is reading books wrote in this language.

Comment: I have tried that, doesnt work, if you input 3 or 7, the message "The number appears more than once." is displayed, you are only checking if the number is on the list.

Comment: Ooooh... Wait a second, I'll fix it.

Comment: Is the same answer posted by Alikbar, Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    if (!set.add(number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " appears more than once.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(number + " does not appear more than once.");
    }
```